# Форма регистрации: ошибка ввода email

Tags: ajax, php

Друзья, у меня такой вопрос! Есть форма регистрации! На неё повешан такой `ajax` скриптик

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "key=" + em,
    url: "/proverka.inc.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
        if(data.key == "error")
        {
        $("#proverka2").text("Данный email уже используется!");
        }
        else
        {
        $("#proverka2").text("ok");
        }
    }
});
```

он направлен на `php` скриптик

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbcon.inc.php');
if($_POST)
{
    $key = $_POST['key'];
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            if($myrow['email'] == $key)
            {
                $key = array("key" => "error");
                echo json_encode($key);
            }
        }
}
?>
```

проблема в том, что он работает, при повторном наборе одного того же ящика выходит уведомление, мол такой емайл уже есть но, стоит вбить туда оригинальный (которого нет в базе) емэйл ничего не меняется и уведомление не исчезает. Вот бы мне советик)

Comment: Что в консоль падает? Какое сообщение об ошибке. Вероятнее всего, что так как скрипт ничего не возвращает, то data в функции success равна undefined или null, что приводит к ошибке в строке data.key и не выполняется дальше код.  
Рекомендую изучить назначение WHERE в SQL.

Comment: data.key как раз таки возвращается! первый иф срабатывает елсе не срабатывает почему?

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    $response=Array("key"=>"");
     while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         if($myrow['email'] == $key) {
               $response["key"]= "error");
         }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);

Comment: а помоему проблема в ajaxe))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$key'");
mysql_close();
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
{
    $key = array("key" => "error");
    echo json_encode($key);
}
```

Comment: php и у меня работает)

        if(data.key == "error")
        {
        $("#proverka2").text("Данный email уже используется!");
        }
        else
        {
        $("#proverka2").text("ok");
        }

if в аяксе тоже срабатывает! а вот в else не срабатывает! к примеру я вбиваю емэйл pupkin@mail.ru, если он есть в базе, то выводится "Данный email уже используется!" после я ввожу sumkin@mail.ru, ничего не меняется предупреждение так и стоит на месте...